# hide <li> from a list 

Tags: jquery

I can't find the way to do a very simple thing:
I have some `<li>` with a class like the following:

```
<li class="picture 62033">lala</li>
<li class="video 41463">lala</li>
<li class="video 53553">lala</li>
<li class="video 53554">lala</li>
<li class="video 51483">lala</li>
<li class="video 36715">lala</li>
```

displayed on a page where I also have this div (the number changes from page to page)

```
<div id="nodenid">51483</div>
```

I just want to .hide() the `<li>` with that ID.
Something like this

```
$(".mypage").find('li').hide();
```

but that, of course, hides all of them :)

How can I get the value from the #nodenid and use it to hide the matching `<li>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("LI." + $("#nodenid").html() ).hide();
```

The argument of $() is CSS selector. So, to select LI with class 1321132 you need to use $("LI.1321132") or just $(".1321132")

Comment: Thanks!! I couldn't find the + operation inside the $(), now I know how to do it (and it works)

Comment: + is just string operation, it has nothing to do with jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var classname = $('#nodenid').val();
$("." + classname).hide();
```

Comment: That seems to work too. I did the the first line myself, with the .val() or .html() but I didn't know about the plus... thanks